# How to copy a collection as subcollection in firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `users` collection and `articles` collection. Every user starts with all the articles in `articles` collection which I store as sub-collection of the user and I only keep the articles which the user has not read. When the user reads an document from `article` collection, I remove it from user's sub-collection.  The problem is when a new user signup, I have to fetch all the documents in articles collection and copy over to user's sub-collection which is unnecessary bandwidth usage. Is there any way to minimise it? Is my database model is good enough?

Answer (score 0):

I am more familiar with firestore than firebase but I can give you some ideas until someone better comes along!

You can avoid copying the entire articles by just keeping a list of article IDs for each user that can be used to look up the article in the main list. This list could either be a sub collection or just an array in the user document.

If you were really concerned about bandwidth you could store a list of all the articles in a top level document (that would have to be updated every time you added or removed an article). This stinks a bit of duplication and makes the model more fragile (you must keep two things in sync) but would allow you just to copy this small list instead.

A different approach, if your articles tend to be read in order, is that you could combine a list of unread articles with another field that indicates the latest read article - anything after this article can be considered unread even if not in the list. A new user would then just have this new field set to 0 to indicate no articles read. This also means you wouldn't need to add new articles to all users as each user would check for any articles newer than this new field when they access your service.

Hopefully this can give you some ideas to try and play around with!